# C++ self referencing class

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have to admit my C++ is a bit rusty. In a project I try to create a vector of classes and use them. There is a problem because I want to identify each entry of the vector with a unique pointer to it for fast access but it does not work. Here is a minimal example of my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo{
public:
Foo() { ptr = this; }
~Foo() {}
Foo * ptr;
};

int main()
{
std::vector<Foo> vec;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
  vec.push_back(Foo());
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
 std::cout << "Object Self-Pointer: " << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(vec[i].ptr) << std::endl; 
}
```

Actual output:

```
Object Self-Pointer: bfbebc18
Object Self-Pointer: bfbebc18
```

Intended output:

```
Object Self-Pointer: bfbebc18
Object Self-Pointer: bfbebc1c
```

(some pointers to the actual objects).

I hope you can help me with this issue, thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that it's much simpler to get the address of an object with `&` instead of maintaining a member variable that always contains that value. So you would say `&vec[5]` instead of `vec[5].ptr` and wouldn't have to bother with copy constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: @sth thank you for mentioning that but I need to make sure always the same pointer is used because i use it at different places to identify the class. Just using "&" doesn't guarantee me that the same pointer is used (does it?) :)

Comment: what you really want is a map

Comment: @Listing If you are only using it for identifying the class, you should take a look at this: http://asust.in/0063

Comment: vector guarantees constant-time random access to the elements, so I'm not sure what is gained by getting these pointers.

Comment: I see you guys are right, I will rewrite my program without using those pointers.

Comment: `&` will return the address of the object, so if it's the same object then it will return the same value. If you create a copy of an object, that copy will have a new address. If that's the problem you are trying to work around, than the more straight forward solution would be to avoid making unintentional copies, not to have the copies carry around a pointer to the "original" object. But without more details it's hard to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do this:

```
vec.push_back(Foo());
```

A new temporary `Foo` object is created, but each time it is created in the same address (because it is created on stack and the stack pointer is the same). So the `this` pointer, and therefore the `ptr` member of each of these instances is the same.

When you add each instance to the vector, the default **copy constructor** is called, so the `ptr` member is copied, and therefore all instances in the vector have the same value.

Answer (score 3):

std::vector stores copies of the object (it is a requirement that type of object is copy-constructable). In this case, Foo's copy-constructor is auto generated by the compiler.

So when you do push_back(Foo()), you're doing:

```
1) Create a Foo() object. Set ptr to bfbebc18
2) Copy it, and put it into vector<Foo>
3) Delete the original Foo from which it came
4) Create a new Foo() object. Set ptr to bfbebc18 (the same location is used because it's temporary)
5) Copy it and put it into vector<Foo>
```

Comment: Would the problem be solved if he used 'vector<Foo*>', and used vec.push_back(new Foo()) ?

Comment: @Topo maybe but I don't want to destroy the objects on my own.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `push_back(Foo())` an object is constructed and then `vector` will take a copy of that object. As `Foo` is using the default copy constructor it will store the `this` pointer of the temporary object created by `Foo()`. The address of the temporary object appears to be the same in both iterations of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the problem is that `push_back` pushes a *copy* of the object onto the stack, which is created using the copy constructor, which does a memberwise copy of the member variable.

One way to address this would be to define a copy constructor to do what you want; e.g.:

```
Foo(const Foo& rhs) { ptr = this;}
```

Running with this, I got the output:

```
Object Self-Pointer: 4b0308
Object Self-Pointer: 4b030c
```